# AWS Gateway custom domain using cloudflare.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to the serverless term, and need a little help setting up a custom domain on the AWS gateway.

Everything works great with the endpoint generated by aws ...execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v1/user/1

I have tried many things, both flexible SSL on cloudflare (ends in redirect loops) and FULL SSL (where I upload / type certificates info and RSA Root in the chain (no idea if this is correct)) it works.. but really slow, direct call to the gateway endpoint takes about 200ms YEAR - but with the custom domain it takes up to 2s. BAH :(

so I think it must be the wrong way to do this.

I found the root certificates I used for the chain info here.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218689638-What-are-the-root-certificate-authorities-CAs-used-with-CloudFlare-Origin-CA-

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you follow the guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html ? We can't provide instructions for specific CAs.

Comment: Yep .. And it worked great, but don't know why calls to my custom domain takes about 2000ms. to execute, and when calling the gateway api directly it only takes under 200ms. I think I do something wrong with the certificates, but can't figure out what.

Comment: Can you describe your end-to-end architecture?

Comment: Have you tried using an AWS certificate for your custom domain? They are free by the way. Also if it's something certificate related, you could repeat the test without encryption on HTTP and this would help confirm whether it was SSL related or not.

Comment: @pkdkk, did you ever resolve this? I'm current at the 'SSL handshake failed' stage of this journey, and wondering if it's worth investing time in.

Comment: I also came to the same issue. It's either an infinite redirect loop (when the CNAME goes though a Cloudflare proxy). Or invalid SSL certificate other wise...).
@pkdkk Did you found a work around?